# Problem with Transparency in menu

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel, themes

When i have the Chrome not full on my monitor the Transparency in the bar where i see the "Aplications", the hours, and the icons is transparent
[image]

but when I expand the chrome for see totally in my screen, the bar goes black
[image]

Is there any way to fix this with every program? I like the transparency in the bar

Sorry, im newbie in linux, and I dont know if this is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work (I can't try at my own OS because my wingpanel modified by code):

Open terminal and:

```
dconf-editor
```

(if you don't have dconf-editor simply `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`)

Then search (CTRL + F) for wingpanel.

When wingpanel page opened, uncheck **auto-adjust-alpha** and change **background-alpha** to **0**.

This should make your wingpanel transparent both at maximized windows and non-maximized windows.

Of course you can adjust **background-alpha** as you wish to your own preference.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Loki? The only entry I get when searching for `wingpanel` in `dconf-editor` is `use-transparency`.